# How to run a Personal Workbook Macro using pywin32 in Python?

Tags: python, excel, macros, vba

I'm trying to run a Personal Workbook Macro from Python with 0 arguments.  So far, this is my code:

```
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.application")
xl.Visible = 1

if os.path.isfile('delete_this_file.xlsx'):
    workbook = xl.Workbooks.Open('delete_this_file.xlsx')
else:
    workbook = xl.Workbooks.Add()
    workbook.SaveAs(os.getcwd() + '\\delete_this_file.xlsx')  

xl.Workbooks.Add("C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Excel\\XLSTART\\PERSONAL.XLSB")
xl.Application.Run('LoopThruFiles')
xl.DisplayAlerts = 0
xl.Application.Quit()
del xl
```

But Python kicks back the Windows error: "Cannot run the macro 'LoopThruFiles'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

However, I have enabled the "Trust access to the VBA project object model" checkbox in the Trust center.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xl.Application.Run('PERSONAL.XLSB!LoopThruFiles')
```

See:  http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm

Comment: Just tried it - the new error says:

    "Cannot run the macro 'C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Excel\\XLSTART\\PERSONAL.XLSB!LoopThruFiles'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

Comment: Are macros enabled?  If you open that workbook manually can you run the macro?  I don't think this is related to "Trust access to the VBA project object model" setting, but the the general macro security setting